# Displacement of a point on a circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

There is a mark on a wheel of radius $30$ cm. The mark is in contact with a horizontal plane. The wheel rotates to a distance of $10\pi \approx 31.4$ cm.

$1.$ What is the angle that the old position of the mark makes with the new position?

$2.$ What is the distance between the new position of the mark with that of the ground?

[point B can be anywhere on the circle]

[image]

Comment: Hints: 1. An angle $\theta$ at the center of a circle of radius $r$ subtends an arc of length $r\theta$ on the circumference. 2. Presumably your wheel _rolls without slipping_.

Answer (score 3):

The mark takes a trip on the dotted curve which is displayed on the animation below. The parametric equations of this curve, named as **cycloid**, are

$$\begin{align}
x_A&=R\phi-R\sin\phi \\
y_A&=R-R\cos \phi
\end{align} \qquad 0 \le \phi \le \pi/3$$

Where $R$ is the radius of the circle.

Take a look at this animation. It is exactly made by your data included in the question. It may help to imagine better.

Can you derive the parametric equation?
Can you answer your questions based on the parametric equations?

[image]

Comment: @Rian: Could you get something out of this? :)

Comment: This was really helpful..Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @Rian: You can accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark beside it, if you the see this one as most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for your first question $r\theta = arc length$

Hint for your second question: you can make a triangle with the lines you've drawn, this triangle will be isoceles (remember the sum of angles in a triangle is $\pi$). I'm assuming the ground makes an angle of $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ with the radius at A (correct me if I'm wrong). Try and make use of the sine rule to find a certain side of the triangle (I'll leave you to figure out which side). After doing all of this, you should be able to calculate the height of B from the ground by make use of $sin\alpha = \dfrac{opp}{hyp}$.

EDIT: I'm including the sine rule in case you don't know it. For a triangle ABC, with sides a,b,c opposite to their respective angles (i.e a is to the opposite side as A, etc) $\dfrac{sinA}{a}= \dfrac{sin B}{b} = \dfrac{sinC}{c}$

EDIT: I'm including the answer:

Let $\angle AOB = \theta$

$r\theta = 30\theta = 31.4$

$\therefore \theta = \dfrac{31.4}{30}$

Also Note that: 
$\angle OAB$ = $\angle OBA = \dfrac{\pi - \theta}{2}$

Let X be the point on the ground directly below B.

$\therefore \angle BXA = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Note that $\angle OAX = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ because the ground is a tangent to the circle at the point A.

$\therefore \angle BAX = \dfrac {\pi}{2}- \angle OAB$

Now, using the sine rule:

$\dfrac{sin\theta}{AB}$ = $\dfrac {sin\angle OAB}{r}$

Solve for AB by plugging in $\theta$ and $\angle OAB$ and $r$.

Now

$BX = AB \times sin\angle BAX$. BX is the height of B from the ground. Done. Hope this helped. :)

[image]

Comment: sorry..I didn't get the isoceles triangle there. can u pls make it clear?

Comment: @Rian Join a line from A to B

Comment: But it's not a right angled triangle

Comment: @Rian Consider Origin to be $O$. Then $\Delta AOB$ is isoceles.

Comment: ya..i got that it's isosceles but it's not a right angled triangle..right?

Comment: Let the point X be on the ground directly below B. Then $\Delta ABX$ is right angled

Comment: Likewise $\Delta AOX$ is right angled

Comment: Sorry again ..but i couldn't calculate the height from the ground..Can u pls help me

Comment: I've included more in my answer.

Comment: am infact confused with the second part of the question

Comment: Ok after you've drawn AB, it becomes the hypotenuse of the right angled triangle ABX. I'd recommend you to draw this on a piece of paper so that it becomes easier to understand.

Comment: After you draw that triangle, $AB \times sin(\angle BAX)$ is the displacement of B from the ground.

Comment: okay done..but we don't know BX and AX. and it's BX that we need to calculate.

Comment: BX is calculated by what I put in my last comment. You don't need AX.

Comment: But we haven't introduced with the concept of sin and cos yet. (Am a high school student)

Comment: Nice, So am I !!! But if you haven't done sin and cos yet, why have you used the trigonometry tag?

Comment: some of my seniors suggested.

Comment: I too suggest that you learn what at least sin is, because it is required for this question.

Comment: Okay.. Thank you so much for your answer. It helped a lot!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept it if you found it helpful.

Comment: @Rian I edited it to include an image. Hopefully you understand it completely now. I've also included a definition for the sine of an angle in a right angled triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Angle subtended at center of by circle rolling without slipping

$$ x/r = \theta $$

$$ 31.4 /30 \approx 1.0467 \text{radians or } \approx 60 ^0$$

Displacement is $\frac16$ of circle circumference contacting on the ground.

Comment: But is it really the arc length that we need to consider or the horizontal distance?

Comment: @Narasimham displacement is only curved on non-euclidian space

Comment: As I understod when it rolls without slip, the arc length, x-axis displacements of point of contact, and of the circle center are all same... as in a cycloid case.

Comment: @ S Mo OK, from the question, I meant (implied) x-displacement as that of interest , changed it.